# js If/else statement on second click to rotate image

Tags: javascript, if-statement, onclick

I need to rotate an image on the same onClick attribute. So, after first click image1 should change to image2, and on second click image2 should change back to image1. I wrote code bellow but it only change once, from image 1 to image2, but second click doesn't work anything.

```
function changeImage() {
  if (document.getElementById("image").src == "./images/image1.jpg") {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "./images/image3.jpg";
  }

  else {
    document.getElementById("image").src = "./images/image1.jpg";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an assignment statement when you intended a comparison. Change this:

```
if (document.getElementById("image").src = "./images/image1.jpg") {
```

to this:

```
if (document.getElementById("image").src === "./images/image1.jpg") {
```

A working example:

```js
function changeImage() {
  if (document.getElementById("image").src ===
    "https://via.placeholder.com/100x150") {
    document.getElementById("image").src =
      "https://via.placeholder.com/150x100";
  }

  else {
    document.getElementById("image").src =
      "https://via.placeholder.com/100x150";
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeImage()">Change Image</button><br/><br/>

<img id="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x150">
```

Comment: tried but then doesn't wrok any changes, nothing happen.

Comment: If it still doesn't work, you have something else wrong. See the working example I added above.

Comment: For some reason it works with absolute path but not with relative filesystem path, that's why I didn't have changes. Any ideas how to make to work with relative path?

Answer (score 0):

As t@terrymorse said - you have an assignment operator instead of a comparison operator. However there is a simpler way to achieve your toggle.

Create an array of the image src's and on the button click increment a counter that is then used with the modulo operator to select a different src that is applied to the image.

Using this approach you can have any number of images - and the button click will cycle through the array and return to the start image when the modulus == 0.

```js
const images =[
'https://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/15234-Cream-and-white-fluffy-kitten-sitting-white-background.jpg',
'https://image.freepik.com/free-photo/little-fluffy-kitten-maine-coon_106368-5.jpg'
];

const imgsLength = images.length;
const image = document.getElementById("image");
 
function changeImage(el) {
   const newIndex = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-index'))+1;
   el.setAttribute('data-index', newIndex);
   const  newSrc= images[newIndex % imgsLength];
   image.src = newSrc;
}
```

```html
<button data-index="0" onclick="changeImage(this)" >Change Image</button>

<hr/>

<img id="image" src="https://www.warrenphotographic.co.uk/photography/bigs/15234-Cream-and-white-fluffy-kitten-sitting-white-background.jpg" width="150">
```